# Storage Firefox OS Viera

Tags: storage, firefox-os, television

Is there any way to access storage using Firefox OS on a Panasonic Viera TV? I am interested in writing my own app for playing back recorded TV shows, but I am unable to find anything on how to read storage.
According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox_OS/TVs_connected_devices device storage is unavailable on the Viera, device-storage:sdcard seems to give the object stuff, though, and after allowing access it keep on says it was unavailable.
For using [Data Stores](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Data_Store_API) the objects (navigator.getDataStores etc.) simply don't exist (undefined)

I hope anybody ran into this issue before and managed to solve it, I'd be quite happy about answers!

Comment: Did you add the right permissions to your app?

Comment: Yes, I did. The onlytime the TV asked me for permissions was when using device-storage:sdcard, and I did accept acces then.

Comment: for data-storage, you might have to use something else than sdcard. Not owning the TV it's hard to tell where things are saved.

Comment: Everything else than sdcard returns null, no matter if i allow it in the manifest.webapp or not. Thus the prompt asking the user if they want to allow access can also only happen on the sdcard one, which doesn't seem to be doing anything at all.